# Waiting till value is stable in asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm correctly receiving the updates to a value from a remote server using a library that uses asyncio. The updates could come quite close to each other, frequently in chunks. I want to run a callback only when the value stabilizes, i.e. stays on the same value for, say, 1 second.

This is the code I have till now:

```
import asyncio
import snapcast.control

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
server = loop.run_until_complete(snapcast.control.create_server(loop, 'localhost', reconnect=True))

# add callback for client #0 volume change
def my_update_func(client):
    print(f"Update for {client.friendly_name}: Volume {client.volume} Muted {client.muted} Status {client.group.stream_status}")

server.clients[0].set_callback(my_update_func)

# keep loop running to receive callbacks and to keep background task alive
loop.run_forever()
```

When the user slides the volume control, this generates this output:

```
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 5 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 6 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 7 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 9 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 12 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 15 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 18 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 20 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 21 Muted False Status idle
Update for Dormitorio: Volume 22 Muted False Status idle
```

I want to react after 1 second only to the last one.

Comment: Can you pass an `async def` function as callback to `set_callback`?

Comment: Idea: You create a task that uses [`wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts) on an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-sync.html#event). When a significant change occurs (value not stabilized), you signal the event. That cancels the wait timeout and the task restarts the wait period. If a timeout occurs, you know the value is stabilized

Comment: I'll try your idea @Homer512, in fact waiting for a timeout was the way I solved this when the library allowed me to block waiting for on new updates.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what would that accomplish?

Comment: Then you could use `asyncio` functions in `my_update_func` which could allow you to achieve what you want.

Comment: @mkrieger1,it seems that `my_update_func`cannot be declared as async. Error is `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_update_func' was never awaited`.
@Homer512 idea feels like polling, in fact, the solution is asking "has the value changed?" every second...

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented @Homer512 idea and it works fine.

```
import asyncio
import snapcast.control

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
server = loop.run_until_complete(snapcast.control.create_server(loop, 'localhost', reconnect=True))

client_volume = 0
current_volume = 0
event = asyncio.Event()

async def stabilize(event):
    global client_volume
    global current_volume
    while(1):
        # Wait for at most 1 second
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), timeout=1.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            if current_volume != client_volume:
                print(f"Volume {client_volume}")
                current_volume = client_volume
        event.clear()

# add callback for client #0 volume change
def my_update_func(client):
    global client_volume
    client_volume = client.volume
    event.set()

server.clients[0].set_callback(my_update_func)
loop.create_task(stabilize(event))

# keep loop running to receive callbacks and to keep background task alive
loop.run_forever()
```

With this, the volume is printed only 1 second after the value is stable:

```
Volume 20
Volume 8
Volume 80
Volume 12
Volume 4
```

Reducing the use of globals should be the topic of another question.

Comment: This solution is polling for the value to change every second. Even when the solution below has less upvotes, consider it as it doesn't do polling

Answer (score 0):

Update: creating the task when the first update comes thru and letting it end when the timeout occurs is a much better way to handle the updates. No need to poll and less globals. Its a mixture of @Homer512 and @mkrieger1 ideas:

```
import asyncio
import snapcast.control

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
server = loop.run_until_complete(snapcast.control.create_server(loop, 'localhost', reconnect=True))

event = asyncio.Event()
task = None

async def stabilize(event, client):
    global task
    # Wait for at most 1 second if the event is not set
    try:
        while (1):
            await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), timeout=1.0)
            event.clear()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print(f"Update for {client.name}: Volume {client.volume} Muted {client.muted} Status {client.group.stream_status}")
    task = None

# add callback for client #0 volume change
def my_update_func(client):
    global task, event
    event.set()
    if task is None:
        task = loop.create_task(stabilize(event, client))

server.clients[0].set_callback(my_update_func)

# keep loop running to receive callbacks and to keep background task alive
loop.run_forever()
```